# Проблема установки Ruby через RVM на Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Пытаюсь установить ruby через rvm. Установил сам rvm.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rvm -v
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Теперь устанавливаю ruby, выдает ошибку

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rvm install ruby
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: debian/8/armhf/ruby-2.2.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Not enough space (297MB) to install ruby (440MB).
```

Дискового пространства достаточно. В чем моя проблема?

**UPDATE:**

Команда mount:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mount
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=469748k,nr_inodes=117437,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-    cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Команда df -h:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       1.3G  882M  310M  75% /
devtmpfs        459M     0  459M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M  6.2M  457M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   60M   20M   41M  34% /boot
```

Команда lsblk:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0   15G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   60M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  1.3G  0 part /
```

Comment: интерпретатор *ruby* лучше установить с помощью пакетного менеджера вашего дистрибутива. но если вы хотите это сделать таким необычным способом, как в вопросе, то прочитайте внимательно последнюю строку про недостаток дискового пространства.

Comment: есть большое подозрение, что пакет с интерпретатором *ruby* у вас уже стоит. но если нет, установить можно командой `$ sudo apt-get install ruby` (если, конечно, хватит места на диске).

Comment: Можно выхлоп mount и df -h ?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin лучше только для тех, кому Ruby нужен лишь для запуска уже написанного софта. Для разработчиков как раз оптимальнее RVM и rbenv, т. к. позволяют иметь несколько версий, возможность ставить новые в автоматическом режиме (т. е. одной командой, в т. ч. прямо из репозитория) и могут ставить не-MRI реализации.

Comment: Добавил все что показывают mount, df -h, lsblk

Answer (score 1):

#### Всё честно, у вас действительно не хватает места :)

Вопрос вообще никак не связан ни с Rails, ни с Ruby, он даже с линуксом связан очень слабо. **Он связан с особенностями установки операционнной системы на Raspberry Pi.**

Основной принятый в сообществе способ — залить с помощью `dd` (и аналогов) образ на SD-карточку, "вслепую". Но надо понимать, что заливание образа таким образом запишет столько байт, сколько есть в образе. Поэтому суммарная ёмкость карточки, если ничего не предпринять, обрежется до размера образа. При этом на карточку пишется и таблица разделов, и содержимое самих разделов, **включая свободное место**. Да, в образ включено свободное дисковое место! Поэтому образ обычно перед публикацией сжимается, чтобы это "свободное место" не приходилось скачивать.

В выхлопе `lsblk` видно, что на карточке 15 гигабайт, а разделов всего на 1.3 гигабайта (рут) и 60 мегабайт (загрузчик). А в выхлопе `df -h` видно, что на рут-разделе осталось всего 310 мегабайт.

Возьмите любой редактор разделов (сам пользуюсь графическим `gparted`) и **расширьте основной раздел (который 1.3 Гб) до края карточки**.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в том что при записи образа ОС на флешку при помощи Win32 Disk Imager теряется весь ее объем (было 16 Гб осталось 50 Мб), решается при помощи https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

Comment: Всё верно, Win32 Disk Imager делает то же, что и `dd`.